# Small Open Economy

Tags: open-economy-macro

In a small open economy, the interest rate is exogenous: The world interest rate. The domestic interest rate can fluctuate momentarily, but because of complete freedom of international flow of funds, it comes back to the world rate. The nominal exchange rate is the equilibrating variable.

Does the graph accurately describe the above?

[image: Small Open Economy in Equilibrium]

Comment: Show your effort to solve the problem, otherwise the question is likely to be closed

Comment: Can you guide me?

Comment: I think it will be enough if you show how you tried to solve the problem, but failed